# Empty Cookie based on IP address

Tags: mod-rewrite, cookie

Is there a way to empty a previous cookie based on source ip?
I need this to be done because of loadbalancing issues.

regards
Geert

Comment: Can you share more details about your setup?

Comment: basicly : a sitecrawler tries to  crawl certain website. this website is proxied through 3 Proxyservers. but because of the cookie it always goes to the same server. the idea is to empty the cookie based on the ip of the crawlerserver so that it goes to other elements aswell.

Comment: If you are able to identify the crawler independently of the IP address, why don't you just give it a new cookie? (A certain cookie for a specific proxy or just outdating the cookie)

Comment: should work, but I am overlooking the correct parameter to outdate it.

Comment: You set an empty value and the expire date to the past, e.g. one year. And make sure you use the same path parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You could always use Disallow: /cookies in a robots.txt based on the user agent?

Or if you must drop a cookie to the crawlers, as described above by initall, to delete a cookie, simply have it expire immediately by setting expire to some time before the current time.
 If you specified a domain and path for the cookie, you have to do the same when you delete it:

Comment: the problem is that those cookies are set by the loadbalancer, to which I have access ...

Comment: <script type="text/javascript"><!--
function delCookie(name) {
  var ThreeDays = 3*24*60*60*1000;
  var expDate = new Date();
  expDate.setTime (expDate.getTime() - ThreeDays);
  document.cookie = name + "=ImOutOfHere; expires=" + expDate.toGMTString();
} 
--></script>

Comment: Take a look at Session persistence on your load balancer and set to something like round robin or least connection, as they will drop a session cookie to retain persistence (sticky sessions)..

Comment: I have no access to the loadbalancer, nor will I ever get it ;-) made a type in last post ;-) ëastiest" way for mne would be to empty the cookie